# PyCharm backgrounds tasks spiking up CPU - how to inspect

Tags: pycharm

Sometimes, when opening certain files, PyCharm spikes up the CPU usage and never goes down unless Power Save mode is on. Obviously it is running some broken background tasks never finish which is killing my CPU, my battery and causing third degree burns to my fingers.

How to inspect the situation to assess what is going on and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What do those file have in common?

Answer (score 1):

Jetbrains offer a way to snapshot and report performance problems in Jetbrains IDEs:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems

You can record CPU profiling snapshot after enabling Java VM flag. PyCharm uses proprietary [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/download/) as a profiling agent. You can download a free evaluation version of the desktop software and open the CPU snapshot dump in that to see where the CPU cycles are spent.

Also PyCharm Community edition is open source, so you can get some insight from Java source code what might be happening.

[image]